# need to know a command for jqModal to close a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

#### Environment:

I am using the *jqModal plugin* for **`jQuery`** to create popups. I have a window that pops up. Then by clicking a trigger inside that window opens another.

#### Requirement:

I need to close the previous window after the new one opens.

I can use `$('#id').jqmHide();`, but that will only hide it. I need it to close completely like when it's using the class `jqmClose` on a clickable input.

I need to close it programmatically without clicks...

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the edit @AP

Comment: To the one who voted down my question.  Could you at least have the audacity to post a comment and reason why you would do such a thing?  I think there are trolls here like most forums.. So far, StackOverflow has really sucked

Comment: The question seems pretty valid to me, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question hasn't gotten much attention, I thought I might as well put a conjecture. If you know which classes it uses to close, you can do something like:

```
const el = $('#id')
el.addClass('jqmClose') //Etc. For animations/hiding
someOtherFunctionToRunOn(el) //For additional processing, like data serializing and propogation
```

Does that help?

Comment: The class only works on input elements with a click event.  I was just wondering if there was an official way.  seems unproductive to leave out such a command.

Comment: Is there a close method for the modal?

Comment: yes, starting here at line 260. [link](https://github.com/briceburg/jqModal/blob/master/jqModal.js) but I wouldn't know how to call it...

Comment: Just try `.close()` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/briceburg/jqModal/blob/master/jqModal.js#L283)